# Need help with nested array notation

Tags: notation

I have ben looking at one specific research paper (here's the link if you would like to see http://mrob.com/users/chrisb/Beyond_Nested_Arrays_V.pdf) and I am having trouble understanding some stuff. the symbols ● , /,  and › have not been giving me great luck in finding any reasonable information on any of these symbols. If anyone can help find out what these mean, that would be greatly appreciated.